# async throwing Stack Overflow in mono

Tags: c#, mono, task-parallel-library, async-await, stack-overflow

I'm writing a console app for Mono, trying to get HttpClient to download some content and deserialize it with Json.NET.

The problem I'm experiencing is that I get a Stack Overflow when I call an async method.

It goes like this, simplified to the core of the isse:

```
public static void Main(string[] args){
  ...
  Manager man = new Manager(){...}; // setting up target url, timeouts etc
  man.RenewAuth().Wait(); //it's async but the first time it runs synchronously
  ...
}

public class Manager{
...
async Task<T> GetAsync<T> (string urlAdd)
{
  var httpRes = await Client.GetAsync (Client.BaseAddress + urlAdd);
  string s = await httpRes.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
  var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> (s);
  return deserialized  ;
}

public async Task RenewAuth () // 
{
  ... // logging in, setting up etc

  // THIS WORKS:
  var aKey = GetAsync<AuthKey> ("/AuthKey?email=" + email).Result; 

  // THIS DOESN'T WORK, CAUSES STACK OVERFLOW:
  var aKey = await GetAsync<AuthKey> ("/AuthKey?email=" + email); 

  ... // store the api auth key from aKey and return
}
}
```

In the console I get this:

```
Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x9a823e19, fault addr: 0xb0221ffc
Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x93b36482, fault addr: 0xb0220ff4
Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x93b36482, fault addr: 0xb021fff4
Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x93b3388a, fault addr: 0xb021effc
Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x93b36482, fault addr: 0xb021dff4
Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x93b36482, fault addr: 0xb021cff4
Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x93b3388a, fault addr: 0xb021bffc
Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x93b36482, fault addr: 0xb021aff4
Stack overflow: IP: 0x9a823e19, fault addr: 0xb0218ffc
Stacktrace:

Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: What's the Mono runtime version? Have you tried the most recent dev branch? Also, you should nail it down to either `Client.GetAsync` or `Content.ReadAsStringAsync`.

Comment: Mono version is what comes with the latest beta from Xamarin, I'd expect it to be the latest. The actual async calls don't matter - I tried multiple combinations and I still can't hit a breakpoint after the line that doesn't work

Comment: `public async Task RenewAuth (){ var aKey = GetAsync<AuthKey> (\*...*\).Result;` Don't do this!!!! Do not use `.Result` in the same code that uses `Async` it will work in a console program but will deadlock anything that has a SynchronizationContext (Pretty much anything else besides a console app)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks, Scott! I did discover that in a different environment by showing ActionsList in Xamarin.Forms without async or with .Wait() or .Result in the command - the actions don't show at all. This, however, was purely for troubleshooting purposes

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this only happens when the debugger is attached, otherwise the code works fine.